# What is the right way to emit masked vmovapd (AVX-512) instructions using ASM?

Tags: assembly, llvm-clang, avx512

I've been trying to write some AVX512 code to transpose a 8x8 matrix of doubles, that is already in 8 zmm registers.

One of the tricks I was trying was to replace 2 shuffles with 1 shuffle and 2 mask_movs, so that there is less port 5 pressure - https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/HxZThj. The example code loads and stores the matrix but for my actual use case I have the matrix in zmm registers and need the transpose to stay in zmm registers.
Clang however decides to just output 3 shuffles instead!

```
void Transpose(double* in, double* out) {
  __m512d __t0, __t1, __t2, __t3, __t4, __t5, __t6, __t7;
  __m512d __tt0, __tt1, __tt2, __tt3, __tt4, __tt5, __tt6, __tt7;
  __m512d row0 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 0 * 8);  //  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
  __m512d row1 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 1 * 8);  //  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
  __m512d row2 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 2 * 8);  // 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
  __m512d row3 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 3 * 8);  // 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
  __m512d row4 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 4 * 8);  // 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
  __m512d row5 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 5 * 8);  // 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
  __m512d row6 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 6 * 8);  // 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
  __m512d row7 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 7 * 8);  // 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63

// IACA_START
  __t0 = _mm512_unpacklo_pd(row0, row1);  // 0  8  2  10  4 12  6 14
  __t1 = _mm512_unpackhi_pd(row0, row1);  // 1  9  3  11  5 13  7 15
  __t2 = _mm512_unpacklo_pd(row2, row3);  // 16 24 18 26 20 28 22 30
  __t3 = _mm512_unpackhi_pd(row2, row3);  // 17 25 19 27 21 29 23 31
  __t4 = _mm512_unpacklo_pd(row4, row5);  // 32 40 34 42 36 44 38 46
  __t5 = _mm512_unpackhi_pd(row4, row5);  // 33 41 35 43 37 45 39 47
  __t6 = _mm512_unpacklo_pd(row6, row7);  // 48 56 50 58 52 60 54 62
  __t7 = _mm512_unpackhi_pd(row6, row7);  // 49 57 51 59 53 61 55 63


  __tt0 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t0, _mm512_setr_epi64(0, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 12, 13), __t2);
  __tt1 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t0, _mm512_setr_epi64(2, 3, 10, 11, 6, 7, 14, 15), __t2);
  __tt2 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t1, _mm512_setr_epi64(0, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 12, 13), __t3);
  __tt3 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t1, _mm512_setr_epi64(2, 3, 10, 11, 6, 7, 14, 15), __t3);
  __tt4 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t4, _mm512_setr_epi64(0, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 12, 13), __t6);
  __tt5 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t4, _mm512_setr_epi64(2, 3, 10, 11, 6, 7, 14, 15), __t6);
  __tt6 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t5, _mm512_setr_epi64(0, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 12, 13), __t7);
  __tt7 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t5, _mm512_setr_epi64(2, 3, 10, 11, 6, 7, 14, 15), __t7);
  // 0 8 16 24 4 12 20 28
  // 2 10 18 26 6 14 22 30
  // 1 9 17 25 5 13 21 29
  // 3 11 19 27 7 15 23 31
  // 32 40 48 56 36 44 52 60
  // 34 42 50 58 38 46 54 62
  // 33 41 49 57 37 45 53 61
  // 35 43 51 59 39 47 55 63


//   __t0 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt0, __tt4, 0x44);  // 0  8 16 24 32 40 48 56 
//   __t1 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt2, __tt6, 0x44);  // 1  9 17 25 33 41 49 57 
//   __t2 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt1, __tt5, 0x44);  // 2 10 18 26 34 42 50 58 
//   __t3 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt3, __tt7, 0x44);  // 3 11 19 27 35 43 51 59 
//   __t4 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt0, __tt4, 0xee);  // 4 12 20 28 36 44 52 60 
//   __t5 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt2, __tt6, 0xee);  // 5 13 21 29 37 45 53 61 
//   __t6 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt1, __tt5, 0xee);  // 6 14 22 30 38 46 54 62 
//   __t7 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt3, __tt7, 0xee);  // 7 15 23 31 39 47 55 63 

 // Tried to replace a pair of shuffles, with 1 shuffle and 2 blends.
 // 2 blends should go to port 0 and be better overall.
 // Clang has other ideas and does port 5 shuffles instead :(
 // Can I convince Clang to do as I say some how?

 {
    __m512d v = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt0, __tt4, 0x4e);       // 4 12 20 28 32 40 48 56
    __t0 = _mm512_mask_mov_pd(__tt0, 0b11110000, v);
    __t4 = _mm512_mask_mov_pd(__tt4, 0b00001111, v);
  }

 {
    __m512d v = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt1, __tt5, 0x4e);  // 6 14 22 30 34 42 50 58
    __t2 = _mm512_mask_mov_pd( __tt1, 0b11110000, v); // 2 10 18 26 34 42 50 58
    __t6 = _mm512_mask_mov_pd(__tt5, 0b00001111, v); // 34 42 50 58
  }

  {
    __m512d v = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt2, __tt6, 0x4e);  // 5 13 21 29 33 41 49 57
    __t1 = _mm512_mask_mov_pd(__tt2, 0b11110000, v);
    __t5 = _mm512_mask_mov_pd(__tt6, 0b00001111, v);
  }

  {
    __m512d v = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt3, __tt7, 0x4e);  // 7 15 23 31 35 43 51 59
    __t3 = _mm512_mask_mov_pd(__tt3, 0b11110000, v);
    __t7 = _mm512_mask_mov_pd(__tt7, 0b00001111, v);
  }

// IACA_END

  _mm512_store_pd(out + 0 * 8, __t0);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 1 * 8, __t1);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 2 * 8, __t2);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 3 * 8, __t3);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 4 * 8, __t4);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 5 * 8, __t5);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 6 * 8, __t6);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 7 * 8, __t7);
}
```

So my next attempt was to write an inline assembly version - https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/LR6aQy. The standalone mov_stuff function looks fine to me, however the program doesn't work. Looking at the assembly, it seems wrong too.

```
__m512d mov_stuff(__m512d src, __mmask8 mask, __m512d a) {
    asm volatile ("vmovapd %[A], %[SRC] %{%[MASK]%}\t"
       :  [SRC] "=v" (src)              //output
       :  [A] "v" (a), [MASK] "Yk" (mask));   //inputs
       return src;
}

// Transpose of 8x8 matrix.
// Load stores only done to generate relevant code.
// In actual code the matrix can stay completely in registers
// for multiple iterations.
// Only interested in the register ops, hence the IACA annotations there.
// Severely port 5 limited.
void Transpose(double* in, double* out) {
  __m512d __t0, __t1, __t2, __t3, __t4, __t5, __t6, __t7;
  __m512d __tt0, __tt1, __tt2, __tt3, __tt4, __tt5, __tt6, __tt7;
  __m512d row0 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 0 * 8);  //  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
  __m512d row1 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 1 * 8);  //  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
  __m512d row2 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 2 * 8);  // 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
  __m512d row3 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 3 * 8);  // 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
  __m512d row4 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 4 * 8);  // 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
  __m512d row5 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 5 * 8);  // 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
  __m512d row6 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 6 * 8);  // 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
  __m512d row7 = _mm512_load_pd(in + 7 * 8);  // 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63

// IACA_START
  __t0 = _mm512_unpacklo_pd(row0, row1);  // 0  8  2  10  4 12  6 14
  __t1 = _mm512_unpackhi_pd(row0, row1);  // 1  9  3  11  5 13  7 15
  __t2 = _mm512_unpacklo_pd(row2, row3);  // 16 24 18 26 20 28 22 30
  __t3 = _mm512_unpackhi_pd(row2, row3);  // 17 25 19 27 21 29 23 31
  __t4 = _mm512_unpacklo_pd(row4, row5);  // 32 40 34 42 36 44 38 46
  __t5 = _mm512_unpackhi_pd(row4, row5);  // 33 41 35 43 37 45 39 47
  __t6 = _mm512_unpacklo_pd(row6, row7);  // 48 56 50 58 52 60 54 62
  __t7 = _mm512_unpackhi_pd(row6, row7);  // 49 57 51 59 53 61 55 63


  __tt0 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t0, _mm512_setr_epi64(0, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 12, 13), __t2);
  __tt1 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t0, _mm512_setr_epi64(2, 3, 10, 11, 6, 7, 14, 15), __t2);
  __tt2 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t1, _mm512_setr_epi64(0, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 12, 13), __t3);
  __tt3 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t1, _mm512_setr_epi64(2, 3, 10, 11, 6, 7, 14, 15), __t3);
  __tt4 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t4, _mm512_setr_epi64(0, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 12, 13), __t6);
  __tt5 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t4, _mm512_setr_epi64(2, 3, 10, 11, 6, 7, 14, 15), __t6);
  __tt6 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t5, _mm512_setr_epi64(0, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 12, 13), __t7);
  __tt7 = _mm512_permutex2var_pd(
      __t5, _mm512_setr_epi64(2, 3, 10, 11, 6, 7, 14, 15), __t7);
  // 0 8 16 24 4 12 20 28
  // 2 10 18 26 6 14 22 30
  // 1 9 17 25 5 13 21 29
  // 3 11 19 27 7 15 23 31
  // 32 40 48 56 36 44 52 60
  // 34 42 50 58 38 46 54 62
  // 33 41 49 57 37 45 53 61
  // 35 43 51 59 39 47 55 63


  // Does not work and asm looks wrong.
 {
    __m512d v = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt0, __tt4, 0x4e);       // 4 12 20 28 32 40 48 56
    __t0 = mov_stuff(__tt0, 0b11110000, v);
    __t4 = mov_stuff(__tt4, 0b00001111, v);
  }

 {
    __m512d v = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt1, __tt5, 0x4e);  // 6 14 22 30 34 42 50 58
    __t2 = mov_stuff( __tt1, 0b11110000, v); // 2 10 18 26 34 42 50 58
    __t6 = mov_stuff(__tt5, 0b00001111, v); // 34 42 50 58
  }

  {
    __m512d v = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt2, __tt6, 0x4e);  // 5 13 21 29 33 41 49 57
    __t1 = mov_stuff(__tt2, 0b11110000, v);
    __t5 = mov_stuff(__tt6, 0b00001111, v);
  }

  {
    __m512d v = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__tt3, __tt7, 0x4e);  // 7 15 23 31 35 43 51 59
    __t3 = mov_stuff(__tt3, 0b11110000, v);
    __t7 = mov_stuff(__tt7, 0b00001111, v);
  }

// IACA_END

  _mm512_store_pd(out + 0 * 8, __t0);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 1 * 8, __t1);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 2 * 8, __t2);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 3 * 8, __t3);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 4 * 8, __t4);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 5 * 8, __t5);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 6 * 8, __t6);
  _mm512_store_pd(out + 7 * 8, __t7);
}
```

To isolate the problem I tried to write a test program to see if I could get my assembly version to work - https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TY7iv6. In this test program the standalone versions of mov_stuff_non_asm() and mov_stuff_asm() look identical, however when I use them in a program, the asm version compiles to what looks to me like garbage.

```
__m512d mov_stuff_non_asm(__m512d src, __mmask8 mask, __m512d a)
{
  return _mm512_mask_mov_pd(src, mask, a);    
}

// Trying to emulate mov_stuff_non_asm here.
// Assembly on its own looks identical to the non-asm version.
// But in a full program it compiles to rubbish as seen in the main_asm
// program.
__m512d mov_stuff_asm(__m512d src, __mmask8 mask, __m512d a)
{
    asm volatile ("vmovapd %[A], %[SRC] %{%[MASK]%}\t"
       :  [SRC] "=v" (src)              //output
       :  [A] "v" (a), [MASK] "Yk" (mask));   //inputs
       return src;

}

int main_asm() {
  __mmask8 upper_lower = 0b11110000;
  __mmask8 lower_upper = 0b00001111;

  __m512d t0 = _mm512_setr_pd(0, 8, 16, 24, 4, 12, 20, 28);
  __m512d t4 = _mm512_setr_pd(32, 40, 48, 56, 36, 44, 52, 60);
  __m512d v = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(t0, t4, 0x4e); // 4 12 20 28 32 40 48 56
  __m512d new_t0 = mov_stuff_asm(t0, upper_lower, v);

  DoStuff(new_t0);
}

int main_non_asm() {
  __mmask8 upper_lower = 0b11110000;
  __mmask8 lower_upper = 0b00001111;

  __m512d t0 = _mm512_setr_pd(0, 8, 16, 24, 4, 12, 20, 28);
  __m512d t4 = _mm512_setr_pd(32, 40, 48, 56, 36, 44, 52, 60);
  __m512d v = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(t0, t4, 0x4e); // 4 12 20 28 32 40 48 56
  __m512d new_t0 = mov_stuff_non_asm(t0, upper_lower, v);

  DoStuff(new_t0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any good documentation on how to write masked AVX-512 operations using inline asm. Or maybe if I can coax Clang in some other way to do what I really want it to do?

Comment: Can you try changing your constraint for SRC from `"=v"` to `"+v"`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd. That's right. That was the problem. The "src" register is both a src and a destination and the "+" accomplishes that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Why inline asm?  Do gcc and clang not compile `_mm512_mask_blend_pd` efficiently to [`vblendmpd zmm{k}{z}, zmm, zmm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vblendmpd:vblendmps)?  That lets you copy-and-blend, instead of a destructive `vmovapd` with merge masking which probably requires the compiler to copy the register first.

Comment: @PeterCordes. Clang seems to change a blend to a vmovapd and then change that to a shuffle just like in my example. Code: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CTiD3D

Comment: Oh, well that sucks and should be reported to clang as a missed optimization, especially if you can prove it with a microbenchmark.  (But with more surrounding code that uses other ports, fewer total uops could be an overall throughput win so we'd need LLVM to be smarter about counting uops in loops to decide on a strategy.)  So maybe using `vblendmpd` from inline asm would be best, with an output-only `"=v"` operand.

Comment: BTW, many of your shuffles could be 128-bit granularity with an immediate control, like [`_mm512_shuffle_f64x2(__m512d a, __m512d b, int imm);`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vshuff32x4:vshuff64x2:vshufi32x4:vshufi64x2) `VSHUFF64x2` instead of `vpermt2pd`

Comment: @PeterCordes, which ones where you thinking re vperm2pd -> vshuf64x2?

The vperm2pd ops that I emit, use the following index registers:
_mm512_setr_epi64(0, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 12, 13) AND
_mm512_setr_epi64(2, 3, 10, 11, 6, 7, 14, 15).
Both of these have lanes from each zmm input in either 256 bit half. AFAICT you can't achieve this with vshuff664x2. AFAICT vshuff664x2 requires the first 256 bit half of the result to be filled entirely with some combination of 128 bit chunks of input "a" and the second half be filled entirely with some combination of 128 bit chunks of input "b".

Comment: @Rajiv: oh you're right, I didn't check the docs for the 128-bit shuffle.  There aren't enough bits in an imm8 for arbitrary selection of 4 chunks from the 2x4 lanes of the 2 inputs, so it's like `shufps` but for lanes instead of dwords.  So you do need a vector-controlled shuffle, not immediate.  (BTW, it's `vpermT2pd`, not `vperm2pd`.  selecting between `t` and `i` versions is left up to the compiler in the intrinsics API, but the `t` stands for replacing the table instead of the index.)

Comment: If there are any shuffles you could do with 256-bit granularity, `vinsertf64x4` may be an option to save a control vector.  This would gain performance on KNL, where 2-input shuffles with granularity smaller than 128-bit have 2-cycle throughput vs. 1-cycle for 1-input and 128-bit /  256-bit shuffles.  (No gain on Skylake, though.)  Also a merge-masked `vinsertf64x4` could broadcast and then replace the low element in the destination or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes. Thanks, that makes sense. I am mostly targeting Skylake.  There are shuffles with 256-bit granularity so I'll try `vinsertf64x4` . Some more things to try, though my experiments so far point to the transpose ultimately not being great for the overall code due to port 5 contention. The reason I needed the transpose was that it would help me save a lot of multiplies (bringing a sparse matrix from the RHS of a mat-mul to the LHS), but the port 5 contention makes this a wash. I'll probably just go back to the simpler version

Comment: Another option might be to combine shuffling with loads, like maybe with some merge-mask broadcast loads to blend with a micro-fused p05 / p23 uop.  That might balance port5 pressure with port 2/3 pressure.  Or `VINSERTF64x4` or 64x2 with a memory source runs on p05 + p23 (micro-fused single uop but with an immediate instead of a mask register).  Ideally you can hide some of the store/reload latency in parallel with other shuffles, but it's still like 5 or 6 cycles vs. 3 for a lane-crossing shuffle.

Comment: I thought about combining shuffling with loads. However, the matrix I am transposing is already in registers. It is itself the result another matrix multiplication. The current implementation with this slightly improved transpose is 45 cycles (transpose plus 2 other matrix muls) - not a lot of room for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer since it seems to have solved the problem.*

Looking at your asm, you are using the constraint `[SRC] "=v" (src)`.  The '=' in this case [indicates](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html) that this variable will be assigned the value of SRC on exit from the asm, but that the input value is ignored (ie an output-only variable).  Since the input value is ignored, clang's optimizers can discard any code that would have calculated the value before this point (since you've told it it's not going to get used).

Changing the '=' to '+' says that the existing value in SRC is *updated* rather than output, which is what I believe you intended here.